# What is the definition of an "active user" of a chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I am trying to understand the "weekly users" stat for my chrome extension that is available at the developer dashboard.

Another post noted that this is the number of weekly, active users (not installed). But I have not seen a definition of "active".

Our extension is a shopping aid that automatically deploys a toolbar if someone hits the landing page of certain shopping pages. Then, there is an opportunity to interact with it.

In this case, would "active" include: anyone using the chrome browser with the extension installed? or anyone who had the extension activate by visiting a site? or anyone who actually interacted with the extension with a positive click?

Comment: Could you please point me toward that question and answer? I searched for some time and did not find this specific question. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

My guess, **but it's not an authoritative answer**, would be "Chrome profiles that requested updates from Web Store".

So, an active user is a Chrome instance that accessed the internet within the time period allowing for an update check, with your extension simply installed.

If you need to track activity within the extension, the preferred method would be Google Analytics event tracking. Tutorial [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_analytics).

Comment: It's probably having the extension installed and enabled.